# Efficient way to ignore whitespace in DB2?

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, jdbctemplate

I am running queries in a large IBM DB2 database table (let's call it T) and have found that the cells for column Identifier tend to be padded not just on the margins, but in between as well, as in: '  ID1  ID2    '. I do not have rights to update this DB, nor would I, given a number of factors. However, I want a way to ignore the whitespace AT LEAST on the left and right, even if I need to simply add a couple of spaces in between. The following queries *work*, but are slow, upwards of 20 seconds slow....

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Identifier LIKE '%ID1%ID2%';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE TRIM(Identifier) LIKE 'ID1%ID2';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE TRIM(Identifier) = 'ID1  ID2';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Identifier)) = 'ID1  ID2';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE LTRIM(Identifier) LIKE 'ID1  ID2%';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE LTRIM(Identifier) LIKE 'ID1%ID2%';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE RTRIM(Identifier) LIKE '%ID1  ID2';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE RTRIM(Identifier) LIKE '%ID1%ID2';
```

Trying to query something like "Select * FROM T WHERE REPLACE(Identifier, ' ', '')..." of course just freezes up Access until I Ctrl+Break to end the operation. Is there a better, more efficient way to ignore the whitespace?

================================

UPDATE:
As @Paul Vernon describes below, "Trailing spaces are ignored in Db2 for comparison purpose, so you only need to consider the leading and embedded spaces."

This led me to generate combinations of spaces before 'ID1' and 'ID2' and select the records using the IN clause. The number of combinations means that the query is slower than if I knew the exact match. This is how it looks in my Java code with Jdbc (edited to make it more generic to the key issue):

```
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 30;

    public List<Parts> queryMyTable(String ID1, String ID2) {
        String query="SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (:ids)";
        final Map<String, List<String>> parameters = getIDCombinations(ID1, ID2);
        return namedJdbcTemplate.query(query,parameters,new PartsMapper());
    }


    public static List<String> getIDCombinations(String ID1, String ID2) {
        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        final int literalLength = ID1.length() + ID2.length();
        final int maxWhitespace = MAX_LENGTH - literalLength;
        combinations.add(ID1+ID2);
        for(int x = 1; x <= maxWhitespace; x++){
            String xSpace = String.format("%1$"+x+"s", "");
            String idZeroSpaceBeforeBase = String.format("%s%s%s",ID1,xSpace,ID2);
            String idZeroSpaceAfterBase = String.format("%s%s%s",xSpace,ID1,ID2);
            combinations.add(idZeroSpaceBeforeBase);
            combinations.add(idZeroSpaceAfterBase);
            for(int y = 1; (x+y) <= maxWhitespace; y++){
                String ySpace = String.format("%1$"+y+"s", "");
                String id = String.format("%s%s%s%s",xSpace,ID1,ySpace,ID2);
                combinations.add(id);
            }
        }
        return combinations;
    }
```

Comment: Clean your data at INSERT/UPDATE (trigger?), to make sure there are no leading/trailing whitespaces.

Comment: I should clarify that me and my team do not INSERT/UPDATE this data, and we do not own the table. My question is premised on the assumption that this extraneous whitespace remains.

Comment: Does the first one `Identifier LIKE '%ID1%ID2%' `  also takes time ? Do you have a index on `Indentifier ` column ?

Comment: If your search pattern doesn't start with a `%` or doesn't end with a `%`, there's hope for performance. If it does, the engine needs to read the whole table, and that's going to take time. So, out of those 8 queries, which one do you want to optimize?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, Identifier may have a an index, as the query executes quickly if you have an exact match, and all of the queries above take a similar amount of time.

Comment: @TheImpaler, unfortunately, the whitespace does not always follow the same pattern, which makes eliminating the beginning and ending % problematic, barring another means of ignoring whitespace. 

As far as which query I am looking to optimize, I am looking either for something more efficient or recommendations on whichever query listed above is considered most optimal.

Comment: Found something here with respect to first query only http://db2portal.blogspot.com/2016/06/carefully-code-your-db2-like-predicates.html?m=1 you might have a look into....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trailing spaces are ignored in Db2 for comparison purpose, so you only need to consider the leading and embedded spaces.

Assuming there is an index on the `Identifier`, your only option (if you can't change the data, or add a functional index or index a generated column), is probably something like this

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE
    Identifier = 'ID1 ID2'
OR  Identifier = ' ID1 ID2'
OR  Identifier = '  ID1 ID2'
OR  Identifier = 'ID1  ID2'
OR  Identifier = ' ID1  ID2'
OR  Identifier = '  ID1  ID2'
```

which the Db2 optimize might implement as 6 index lookups, which would be faster than a full index or table scan

You could also try this

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE
    Identifier LIKE 'ID1 %ID2'
OR  Identifier LIKE ' ID1 %ID2'
OR  Identifier LIKE '  ID1 %ID2'
```

which the Db2 optimize might implement as 3 index range scans,

In both examples add more lines to cover the maximum number of leading spaces you have in your data if needed. In the first example add more lines for the embeded spaces too if needed

Comment: Knowing that trailing spaces are ignored actually is the most valuable thing to know here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Index on the expression `REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(Identifier), '\s{2,}', ' ')` and the following query should make Db2 use this index:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T 
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(Identifier), '\s{2,}', ' ') = 'ID1 ID2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search excluding leading and trailing spaces, then no traditional indexes can help you with that, at least as you show the case. To make the query fast, the options I can see are:

**Full Text Search**

You can use a "full text search" solution. DB2 does include this functionality, but I don't remember if it's included by default in the license or is sold separately. In any case, it requires a bit of indexing or periodic re-indexing of the data to make sure the search is up to date. It's worth the effort if you really need it. You'll need to change your app, since the mechanics are different.

**Index on extra, clean column**

Another solution is to index the column without the leading or trailing spaces. But you'll need to create an extra column; on a massive table this operation can take some time. The good news is that once is created then there's no more delay. For example:

```
alter table t add column trimmed_id varchar(100) 
  generated always as (trim(identifier));
```

**Note**: You may need to disable/enable integrity checks on the table before and after this clause. DB2 is picky about this. Read the manual to make sure it works. The creation of this column will take some time.

Then, you need to index it:

```
create index ix1 on t (trimmed_id);
```

The creation of the index will also take some time, but it should be faster than the step above.

Now, it's ready. You can query your table by using the new column instead of the original one (that's still there), but this time, you can forget about leading and traling spaces. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE trimmed_id LIKE 'ID1%ID2';
```

The only wildcard now shows up in the middle. This query will be much faster than reading the whole table. In fact, the longer the string `ID1` is, the faster the query will be, since the selectivity will be better.

Now, if `ID2` is longer than `ID1` then you can reverse the index to make it fast.